# maven error:ArtifactTransferException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.7.2 from http://IP was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.7.2 from/to nexus (http://IP): connection timed out to http://IP

Comment: can you share your full error trace?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

when we see our project we'll find that there are some jar packages missing.
Appear these errors because when your maven download jar packages not download all the jar packages.so we should download jar packages again.
first we should delete local file in this dir .../.m2/repository/ and the file like this org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.5.Final .
and then right click our project click maven update project.
until download the jar package we need the error solve.